# React Native createDrawerNavigator with header/action bar

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have implemented a navigation drawer, but I am unable to show the header/action bar

```js
const RootStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
  },
  {
    intialRouteName: 'Home',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle : {
        backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle : {
        color: 'white',
      },
    },
  }
);


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack/>;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to use drawer navigation as well as a header bar?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your RootStack(Drawer) must be inside a StackNavigator,

```js
const RootStack = createDrawerNavigator(
{
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Details: DetailsScreen,
},
{
intialRouteName: 'Home',
navigationOptions: {
  headerStyle : {
    backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
  },
  headerTintColor: '#fff',
  headerTitleStyle : {
    color: 'white',
    },
   },
 }
);

const AppStack = StackNavigator({ RootStack : { screen: RootStack } });

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppStack/>;
  }
}
```

More info [here](https://shift.infinite.red/react-navigation-drawer-tutorial-a802fc3ee6dc).